# Did Daniel and Vala have a relationship?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, romantic-interest

In *Stargate SG1 - Unending* (S10E20), Daniel and Vala have a relationship during the "time stop". However, they forget about it after Sam turned back time and only Teal'C was able to remember it.

Has a relationship between Daniel and Vala ever been mentioned again in a serious way or was this always just a joke?

Comment: Since Teal'C traveled back in time, their relationship never happened in the prime timeline and the only person who would know is Teal'C of course. Assuming he would not want to contaminate the timeline, he probably kept it a secret. Good question though, my +1.

Comment: Probably. I'd just love if in a film or a book, there'd be a _and then Daniel and Vala lived happily together_ without knowing they already had a happy life together.

Comment: What makes you think their 50 years together in an alternate timeline was a "joke"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They did in the final episode of sg1 but then they travel back in time and only Tealc remembers. In that it becomes clear that Daniel does have feelings for Vala but is scared she's not only messing around when she flirts with him

They don't have a relationship in the movies but it is implied there are feelings there

Comment: Yeah, through the series there is never a relationship or ever any real consideration of one. During that episode is the one and only time anything really happens. Throughout the series Vala is never afraid to use her sexuality, but Daniel always rebuffs her until the described scene.